# how to interact with a web server using iOS, without using a webview

Tags: ios

I am trying to get some data out of my wiki server, and send it to my iphone, so i can have nicely formatted data as in any iphone app.

I could indeed just use a webview and load the page, but I am trying to achieve a different kind of UI; I would like to have the values saved on the device after retrieving them from the wiki, and have them added to a tableview, while other info are displayed trough labels or textfield.

My main problem is that i do not know where to start...everyone told me to use a webview and use the DOM to retrieve the data; but I am sure that there must be some other way to accomplish this natively.

Anyone has any suggestions about where to start?

Answer (score 1):

NSURLRequest. Also check out the ASIHTTPRequest library

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Thanks Tom; I've checked NSURLRequest but is not clear to me how do i get over the HTTPS request; since when i try to access the server i get a response saying that the certificate cannot be accepted. IS there any example that shows how to connect to a server via https using NSURL and accept these certificates (or ignore them, since I know that my server can be reached only by my app). Thanks!

Comment: is the time set correctly on the device?  that is the number 1 reason a https session will fail.